# Filter nested lists and trasnform with streams in Java8

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

I have to list of objects. I want locate for key the element of ListA in ListB and later invoke a function that fusion the data. I have this:

```
public List<CarDto> transformData(List<CarDto> listDataA,List<CarDto> listDataB){

    List<CarDto> fusionList = new ArrayList<CarDto>();      

    for(CarDto carDtoDataA:listDataA) {
        for(CarDto carDtoDataB:listDataB) {
            if(null != carDtoDataA && null != carDtoDataB
                    && carDtoDataA.getKey1().equals(carDtoDataB.getKey1())                      
                    && 0==carDtoDataA.getKey2().compareTo(carDtoDataB.getKey2())
                    && carDtoDataA.getKey3().equals(carDtoDataB.getKey3())) {
                fusionList.add(this.fusionDataAB(carDtoDataA,carDtoDataB));
            }
        }
    }
    return fusionList;
}
```

How to write the code below in java 8 using streams to avoid nested loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your `getKey2()` objects not override equals?  It would be a little clearer than compareTo (imho).

Comment: while this is an `O(A*B)` solution, an approach of `groupingBy` using `Arrays.as(k1, k2, k3)`  for both `listDataA` and `listDataB` in `max(O(A), O(B))` runtime would provide you `Map`s to iterate through one and lookup another in constant time to add elements to the `fusionList`. ** are you trying to implement equality here `0 == dataA.getKey2().compareTo(dataB.getKey2())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and use `filter` for conditions on object properties

```
public List<CarDto> transformData(List<CarDto> listDataA,List<CarDto> listDataB){

  List<CarDto> fusionList = new ArrayList<CarDto>();     

  listDataA.stream()
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .forEach(objA-> listDataB.stream()
                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                           .filter(objB-> objA.getKey1().equals(objB.getKey1()))
                           .filter(objB-> objA.getKey2().compareTo(objB.getKey2()) == 0)
                           .filter(objB-> objA.getKey3().equals(objB.getKey3()))
                           .forEach(objB->fusionList.add(this.fusionDataAB(objA, objB)))); 


    return fusionList;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't taking the `listDataB.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)` outside and collecting it to a list and then using it within forEach of listA stream would be better?

Comment: I try this but when i return the list shows error -> "cannot return a void result",  i try with map and collect but the same result ... is embebed in a function and returns List<Object>

Comment: Firstly i don't like having `null` objects in `List`, OP should collect the non null objects into List, since he has it in question i just added it here, secondly this solution is `O(N*N)` which i don't prefer, it will be better if OP can come up with `O(N)` or at least `O(N log N)`

Comment: I will recommend to post the question exactly same with issue your are facing, in the above post i don't see return statement of returning list @iptaboada

Comment: I just did. Thanks for the help!